# div id is constructed by adding vars, now want to get value of this div

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, html, text

This is a project for school, with sort of a hot-or-notgame. User gets 2 pictures placed in either div face1 or in div face2. He can choose his favourite by pressing left/right or s/d.

I'm having the following problem in the if-statement of the function: I know when keys with the code 37 (left arrow) and 83 (s-key) were pressed, the user chooses "face1".

when I show "var w" on my page, it correctly shows **#face1** .
Now when I add quotes around #face1 in winnerid, it correctly shows **"#face1"**
But now when want to get the text in div #face1, it doesn't return anything, altough there is a number there

`<div id="face1"> 432 </div>`

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 37 || e.which == 83) {
  var w = '#face1';
  var winnerid ='"' + w + '"';
  var id= $(winnerid).text();
  $("h1 span").text(id);      

  }
  else if(e.which == 39 || e.which == 68) {
  $("h1 span").text("right");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to include the surrounding quotes for the jQuery selector. Just use:

```
var w = '#face1';
var id= $(w).text();
```

The jQuery function ( `$()` ), accepts a string (among other things) as a selector (among other things). So simply passing a string *variable* containing `#face1` is the same as:

```
var id = $('#face1').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't add quotes to your selector.

Replace

```
var winnerid ='"' + w + '"';
var id= $(winnerid).text();
```

with

```
var id= $(w).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the second line of these 2 statemenets

```
  var w = '#face1';
  var winnerid ='"' + w + '"';    < ----  Remove this 
  var id= $(winnerid).text();
```

to

```
var w = '#face1';
 var id= $(w).text();
```